# Get all string splits

Tags: haskell

Say I have a string:

```
"abc7de7f77ghij7"
```

I want to split it by a substring, `7` in this case, and get all the left-right splits:

```
[ ("abc", "de7f77ghij7")
, ("abc7de", "f77ghij7")
, ("abc7de7f", "7ghij7")
, ("abc7de7f7", "ghij7")
, ("abc7de7f77ghij", "")
]
```

Sample implementation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module StrSplits where

import qualified Data.Text as T

splits :: T.Text -> T.Text -> [(T.Text, T.Text)]
splits d s =
  let run a l r  =
        case T.breakOn d r of
          (x, "") -> reverse a
          (x, y)  ->
            let
                rn = T.drop (T.length d) y
                an = (T.append l x, rn) : a
                ln = l `T.append` x `T.append` d
            in run an ln rn
  in run [] "" s

main = do
  print $ splits "7" "abc7de7f77ghij7"
  print $ splits "8" "abc7de7f77ghij7"
```

with expected result:

```
[("abc","de7f77ghij7"),("abc7de","f77ghij7"),("abc7de7f","7ghij7"),("abc7de7f7","ghij7"),("abc7de7f77ghij","")]
[]
```

I'm not too happy about the manual recursion and `let`/`case`/`let` nesting. If my feeling that it doesn't look too good is right, is there a better way to write it?

Is there a generalized approach to solving these kinds of problems in Haskell similar to how recursion can be replaced with `fmap` and `fold`s?

Comment: Related: `breakOnAll`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:breakOnAll

Comment: You can take a look at the source code https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/src/Data.Text.html#breakOnAll

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah... I've seen it, but mis-read the docs and thought it works as `splitOn` :( Thanks for making me re-read! Anyway, looking at the source it looks like it's doing manual recursion as well, so looks like what I had is a fair approach, right? Or can it be improved in some way (conceptually in this context - not talking about performance or using other libraries, etc.)?

Comment: You could perhaps use a list zipper to create (efficiently!) all candidate pairs with the first item reversed, filter those candidates, and (un)reverse all remaining first items.

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya I did not get the solution you're proposing - do you mind posting it as an answer, so I can see how the code would look like?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import Data.Bifunctor (bimap)

splits' :: T.Text -> T.Text -> [(T.Text, T.Text)]
splits' delimiter string = mkSplit <$> [1..numSplits]
  where
    sections  = T.splitOn delimiter string
    numSplits = length sections - 1
    mkSplit n = bimap (T.intercalate delimiter) (T.intercalate delimiter) $ splitAt n sections
```

I like to believe there's a way that doesn't involve indices, but you get the general idea. First split the string by the delimiter. Then split that list of strings at in two everywhere possible, rejoining each side with the delimiter.

Not the most efficient, though. You can probably do something similar with `indices` from [`Data.Text.Internal.Search`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text-Internal-Search.html) if you want it to be fast. In this case, you wouldn't need to do the additional rejoining. I didn't experiment with it since I didn't understand what the function was returning.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! "I like to believe there's a way that doesn't involve indices" Yeah that was my last question, basically are there conceptually different and more "pleasing" / higher-level approaches.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid indices while maintaining efficiency. But you could write a wrapper using existential types that ties indices to the `Text` they came from, guaranteeing bounds. The whole thing will be a bit awkward, but maybe that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an indexless one.

```hs
import Data.List (isPrefixOf, unfoldr)

type ListZipper a = ([a],[a])

moveRight :: ListZipper a -> Maybe (ListZipper a)
moveRight (_, []) = Nothing
moveRight (ls, r:rs) = Just (r:ls, rs)

-- As Data.List.iterate, but generates a finite list ended by Nothing.
unfoldr' :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> [a]
unfoldr' f = unfoldr (\x -> (,) x <$> f x)

-- Get all ways to split a list with nonempty suffix
-- Prefix is reversed for efficiency
-- [1,2,3] -> [([],[1,2,3]), ([1],[2,3]), ([2,1],[3])]
splits :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
splits xs = unfoldr' moveRight ([], xs)

-- This is the function you want.
splitsOn :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [([a],[a])]
splitsOn sub xs = [(reverse l, drop (length sub) r) | (l, r) <- splits xs, sub `isPrefixOf` r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJhi9NAEP3eX/EoB5fAtnDnh0i5KwiKIOqJ@MkYvG0zSVbT3bi7uUvA/96bTWJawftgSCAz7@3MezNbSfeT6vp4VIfGWI/X0sv1e@U8IuU@WSpUd1cItLowdW7jxcL3DSEQvqqmIQuJW0SpzAR/DB/MA31WZeWx2fxNW23xQfY7QnSejs9ORN8F0izmgh@Nr5Quz7HaCdiNdQF@1wZ9djPkHHddrfDKnbSvlScrPQnsWo@S9BA5FlEozRjqYJB0Tjl2/Z9u68Xk8jJoj84Uyzj8Dwl2eaIVrGUKEH3rAh6JGB1uLrYMdqOyt@Qh6xqPsnfwBq6pFWdGEY/KV9BG06HxPVxb8MDDoXH0UA6WHsg6VloYC2J8r0jv@0BKr8S1eJENuqKUVzDGseCNXHE4B9cihBxki6G7Cw7ZynRy2t4Mdu5k7BJnS@AeDI62vlQsjl9fEYpW770yGr1p2af266nUnR5m@eZXmOHtdu75XGvmu3Y3CkijyTpqgdyahi8B6ZLnxZQYNsZvzojwc7PCLF0MFe5Pt/ceNjsepNJcMzcL8NNYpT0uMDddJkss5W6f5JQUSVJW6keyfI76H9yX/6AenwA)

Basically, traverse a list zipper to come up with a list of candidates for the split. Keep only those that are indeed splits on the desired item, then (un)reverse the prefix portion of each passing candidate.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting approach! This only works on lists though, right? I.e. it only works on `String`, but not applicable to `Text` or splitting based on multi-character strings?

Comment: @levantpied Right.

Comment: You want to split on a sub-string. Not on a single element

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Whoops. Fixed now, @levantpied